# AWS SQS List Triggers from SDK

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

I'm looking for a method to programmatically identify the triggers associated with an SQS queue. Looking through the [SQS sdk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html), it doesn't seem this is possible. I had thought instead to try from the other end, and it appears the [Lambda ListEventSourceMappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listEventSourceMappings-property) function would likely do what I want, since I'm able to provide it with the queue ARN. However, this requires the ListSourceMappings permission on all lambdas (*), which isn't really ideal - though it shouldn't *really* hurt, just not what I want. Is there another mechanism for this that I'm missing, or another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda polls SQS queues. It doesn't appear that way in the console, because they hide some of the details from you, but behind the scenes there is a process running within the AWS Lambda system that is polling your SQS queue and invoking your Lambda function when a message is available.

SQS doesn't push messages to Lambda (or anywhere else). SQS just holds messages and hands them out to anything that asks for them. So from an SQS perspective, there is no knowledge of who the message consumers are.

Given the above, the only way to find what you want is to use the Lambda [ListEventSourceMappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listEventSourceMappings-property) API.